# NodeJS request get return me html code instead of json

Tags: node.js, json, express, get, request

I'm trying to get get a json from a get request it's work in python but in NodeJs that display me the html code source of the page
this is my code :

```
app.get("/well", function(request, response)  {
  const req = require('request');

  const options = {
      url: 'https://swarmmanager.francecentral.cloudapp.azure.com:3000',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
      },
      agentOptions: {
        ca: fs.readFileSync("public/IdaktoPKIRootCA.crt")
      }
  };

  req(options, function(err, res, body) {
      console.log(body);
  });
});
```

and this is another version but same problem:

```
app.get("/well", function(request, response)  {
  g_CnieOidcAddr = 'https://swarmmanager.francecentral.cloudapp.azure.com:3000';
  const options = {
    hostname: 'swarmmanager.francecentral.cloudapp.azure.com',
    port: 3000,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    ca: fs.readFileSync("public/IdaktoPKIRootCA.crt")
};
  const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
    console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);
    console.log('headers:', res.headers);
  
    res.on('data', (d) => {
      process.stdout.write(d);
    });
  });
  
  req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
  req.end();
});
```

i try to do it in python and it's work find that return me a json:

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}
                r = requests.get(g_CnieOidcAddr + '/.well-known/openid-configuration', params={}, headers = headers, verify='./IdaktoPKIRootCA.crt')
                print (r.text)
```

if anyone has an idea i'm a taker ^^ thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

ok that work find i just forgot something at the end of the url so if you come to this page the 2 codes work find to to a request